# JSOUP não pega lista não ordenada (ul > li)

Tags: java, jsoup

Olá, se alguém muito fera em JSOUP puder me socorrer, estou tentando pegar informações de um card deste site "https://www.brasileirao.com.br/". O problema é que as informações ficam dentro de uma lista não ordenada a qual não aparece na solicitação. Aqui está o card:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está a lista:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui vou deixar o meu código:

```java
  Document doc;
         try {
             doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.brasileirao.com.br/").get();
             System.out.println(doc.title());
             Elements boxJogos = doc.select("section.box");
             Elements lis = boxJogos.select("ul.rodadas__jogos, li.rodadas__jogos-card");

             System.out.println(lis);

         } catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(HeloWorld.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
```

//A saída é esta:

```java
TABELA | BRASILEIRÃO SÉRIE A | Brasileirao.com.br
<ul class="rodadas__jogos" id="js-rodadas-jogos"></ul>
CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 1 segundo)

//Como dá pra ver não saiu nem um item da lista. Se alguém puder ajudar vou ficar muito feliz. Obrigado desde já
```

Answer (score 0):

O jsoup utiliza como forma de seleção a syntax do seletor css. Baseado nisso podemos fazer o seguinte:

```
    Elements lis = doc.select("#js-rodadas-jogos > li")
```

Sendo '#' uma marcação de questou pegando a ul pelo seu id 'js-rodadas-jogos', em seguida o '>' significa que estou pegando seus filhos do tipo li

Fonte:

https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax (explicação de como funciona o seletor do jsoup)
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp (explicação de como funciona o css selector)